# Change environment when start sailsJS project

Tags: node.js, sails.js, environment

I have two environment in my sailsjs project: development and production.

[image: This is my config folders]

In local.js I have this:

```
module.exports = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 1349,
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || "production"
}
```

In my development.js I have:

```
module.exports = {
  models: {
    connection: "someMongoDb",
    migrate: 'alter',
    schema : true,
    autoPK: true,
    autoCreatedAt: true,
    autoUpdatedAt: true
  },
  port: 1348
}
```

In my production.js I have:

```
module.exports = {
  models: {
    connection: "mongoDBPro",
    migrate: 'alter',
    schema : true,
    autoPK: true,
    autoCreatedAt: true,
    autoUpdatedAt: true
  },
  port: 1349
}
```

I would like to select one of this environment when I start my sails project. It is possible when I start with "sails lift" say what environment I choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sails lift` by default will uses `--dev`.
You can add `--prod` to the command to specify a production environment.

Sails will set the environment variable `NODE_ENV` and load the correct configuration.

Comment: No, if I use --prod or --dev, only change the name of "environment" but use config/models.js configuration..

Comment: I finally use "--prod" or "--dev" to analyze args of sails lift and choose one environment or the other. Thanks

Comment: `config/models.js` will be used as default values for your configuration.